# Initalize nested objects

Tags: java

I have a series of nested objects, each parent has several children. I have created custom classes to hold this data but now need to understand how to initalize the classes.

The data looks like:

```
2021-06-20 
    AMBULANCE\CA\Los Angeles
        Morning
            4
        Afternoon
            5
        Nights
            5
    AMBULANCE\CA\San Deigo
        Afternoon
            7
        Nights
            6
        Morning 
            4
2021-06-21
     AMBULANCE\CA\Los Angeles
         Night
            6
         Morning
            5
         Afternoon
            5
     ANBULANCE\CA\San Francisco
         Afternoon
            5
         Morning
            4
....
```

To hold this data I have these classes:

```
public class RootNode {
    public RootNode(){}
    public Set<ShiftDate> shiftDateSet;
}

public class ShiftDate {
    public LocalDate date;
    public Set<Location> location;
}

public class Location {
    public Set<ShiftType> shifts;
}

public class ShiftType {
    public enum ShiftTypes {
        MORNING, AFTERNOON, NIGHT
    }
    public Integer count;
}
```

Then I am looping over deserialized JSON to populate my new RootNode custom class:

```
RootNode rootNode = new RootNode();

for (Entities e: rootJsonNode.someEntity) {
    LocalDate someDate;
    someDate = e.dto.startDateTime.toLocalDate();  
         if (!rootNode.get(someDate)) {
              rootNode.shiftDateSet.add(new ShiftDate(date, new Set<Location> ))
              // the line above should add a new date AND add
              // new Set<Location> but do not need to bind to 
              // a name for the Set.
          }
          if (rootNode.get(someDate)) {
              // node already exsists so add stuff and increment counter
          }

  }
```

I am checking to see if a date already exists in the rootNode and if it doesn't add it, but this is where I need assistance: Before adding the date I need to initalize a new ShiftDate and all the child objects.

Ultimately I want to be able to access rootNode.getShiftDate(date).getLocation(location).getShiftType(type).getCount();

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Collections can be initialized at definition point

```
public class RootNode {
    public Set<ShiftDate> shiftDateSet = new HashSet<>();
}

public class ShiftDate {
    public LocalDate date;
    public Set<Location> location = new HashSet<>();
}

public class Location {
    public Set<ShiftType> shifts = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This way when calling the RootNode constructor

```
RootNode rootNode = new RootNode();
```

It will initialize every nested object initializing its sets with empty HashSets
Also... empty constructors are already defined if no other constructor is going to be declared, so it's redundant

EDIT:

To initialize anything more than just an empty set use the constructor

```
public class Location {
    public Set<ShiftTypes> shifts = new HashSet<>();
    public Location() {
        shifts.add(ShiftTypes.MORNING);
        shifts.add(ShiftTypes.AFTERNOON);
        shifts.add(ShiftTypes.NIGHT);
    }
}
```

This time I assumed you wanted the set in Location to be of type ShiftTypes and not ShiftType, otherwise you can't fill it with every enum type because ShiftType itself is not an enum

If ShiftType should be used (because you need the integer) then that's a whole different story you'll have to add a field in ShiftType

```
public class ShiftType {
    public enum ShiftTypes {
        MORNING, AFTERNOON, NIGHT
    }
    public ShiftTypes shiftTypeEnum;
    public Integer count;
    
    public ShiftType(ShiftTypes shiftTypeEnum, Integer count) {
       this.shiftTypeEnum = shiftTypeEnum;
       this.count = count;
    }
}
```

And the above method becomes

```
public class Location {
    public Set<ShiftType> shifts = new HashSet<>();
    public Location() {
        shifts.add(new ShiftType(ShiftTypes.MORNING, 0));
        shifts.add(new ShiftType(ShiftTypes.AFTERNOON, 0));
        shifts.add(new ShiftType(ShiftTypes.NIGHT, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Can you set those new HashSet<>() to already have each of the enum values?

Comment: That's what constructors are for, I'll edit my post and add the info